# Function is working in OnClick but not in OnCreate()

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to show  a countdown timer for the user. A Function(myfunc) is working perfect with a button click. But I want to run it as soon as the activity is created. In the Oncreate method. But myfunc not working in the OnCreate method.

Here is the code of MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private enum TimerState {
    STOPPED,
    RUNNING
}

private static final long TIMER_LENGHT = 60; // Sixty seconds
private long mTimeToGo;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private TimerState mState;

@BindView(R.id.main_timer)
TextView mTimerText;

@BindView(R.id.main_timer_button)
Button mTimerButton;

PrefUtils mPreferences;
long startTime;
Calendar rightNow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mState=TimerState.STOPPED;
    mPreferences = new PrefUtils(this);
    startTime = mPreferences.getStartedTime();
    rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();


            myfunc();



}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    initTimer();
    removeAlarm();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mState == TimerState.RUNNING) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        setAlarm();
    }
}
private long getNow()
{

    return rightNow.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
}

private void initTimer()
{

    if (startTime >= 0)
    {
        mTimeToGo = (TIMER_LENGHT - (getNow() - startTime));
        if (mTimeToGo <= 0)
        { // TIMER EXPIRED
            mTimeToGo = TIMER_LENGHT;
            mState = TimerState.STOPPED;
            onTimerFinish();
        }
        else
        {
            startTimer();
            mState = TimerState.RUNNING;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mTimeToGo = TIMER_LENGHT;
        mState = TimerState.STOPPED;
    }
    updateTimeUi();
}

private void onTimerFinish()
{

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.timer_finished,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mTimerText.setText(R.string.timer_finished);
    mPreferences.setStartedTime(0);
    mTimeToGo=TIMER_LENGHT ;
    updateTimeUi();
}

private void updateTimeUi()
{
    mTimerText.setText(String.valueOf(mTimeToGo));
}

private void startTimer()
{
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeToGo*1000 , 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            mTimeToGo -= 1;
            updateTimeUi();
        }
        public void onFinish()
        {
            mState = TimerState.STOPPED;
            onTimerFinish();
            updateTimeUi();
        }
    }.start();
}


public void myfunc()
{
    if  (mState == TimerState.STOPPED) {
        mPreferences.setStartedTime(getNow());
        startTimer();
        mState = TimerState.RUNNING;
    }
}

public void setAlarm() {
    long wakeUpTime = (mPreferences.getStartedTime() + TIMER_LENGHT) * 1000;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerExpiredReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(wakeUpTime, sender), sender);
    } else {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wakeUpTime, sender);
    }
}

public void removeAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerExpiredReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(sender);
}
```

}

And one utils code is here

```
class PrefUtils {
private static final String STARTED_TIME_ID = "com.whiterabbit.time";
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

PrefUtils(Context c)
{
    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
}

long getStartedTime()
{
    return mPreferences.getLong(STARTED_TIME_ID, 0);
}

void setStartedTime(long started) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
    editor.putLong(STARTED_TIME_ID, started);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

And The Broadcast Receiver is here too

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    b.setSound(notification)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.timer_finished))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.timer_finished))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_clear_all)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    Notification n = b.build();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, n);
}
```

Comment: put your code in onResume

Comment: You are initiating timer in onResume which is called after the onCreate method. Which is why it is not working.

Comment: Explain what you want to do, I am sure there is a simpler way of doing it

Comment: I am using a fix countdowntimer. Even if the user kills the activity, the countdowntimer should run after killing the activity when the user opens app again after killing it should show the time passed. And the time left now

Answer (score 1):

Before Call  myfunc call  initTimer once.Because onResume will be call after onCreate or delay some seconds in oncreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ButterKnife.bind(this);
mState=TimerState.STOPPED;
mPreferences = new PrefUtils(this);
startTime = mPreferences.getStartedTime();
rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
myfunc();     
}
}, 100);//Delay 100ms

}
```

Comment: The Timer is restarting when the activity is coming visible to the user after app switching. Where as it should not start. On Button click it does not restart until the time is finished. Even if the app is killed.

Comment: then this case you delay some millseconds  then call myfunc(); oncreate

Comment: still the same problem as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: whats is mState status when its reach onCreate method?

Comment: It is by default mState=STOPPED.

Comment: then it will be working correctly  based on myfunc ?

Comment: let me check again bro

Comment: It is working Fine. Well Thank You. Can you help me in one more thing?

Comment: IF I change the 60 seconds to 3600 sec, and i want them to display like 59:59. And start a proper one hour countdown, How can I do that in the same code???

Comment: still there is problem for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... I thought I'd give some time for the onCreate to load all data from savedInstanceState.

Clicking the button programmatically after some delay,

```
button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //delay button 
     public void run() {  
         button.performClick();
         button.setPressed(true); 
        
     }
 }, 800);
```

Comment: it would be nice to give some explanation of why you think this will work